# Change defined textfield properties

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have a free text field defines as follows

```
t.text :freeText
```

in the gui it is defined

```
<p>
  <b>Freetext:</b>
  <%= @recipe.freeText %>
</p>
```

I get a textfield on the html. I want to be able to present large input text with multiline (kind of like JTextArea instead of JTextField). How do I declare it?

Comment: Does this question really about RoR and not about html?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [text_area](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-text_area) tag helper, like this:

```
<% form_for(@recipe) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :freeText, :html => {:cols => "40", :rows => "10"} %> 
<% end %>
```

By the way, please read a Ruby style guide to know how to name variables properly (among other things). The following [one](https://github.com/styleguide/ruby) from GitHub is great.